# Why I can't visit http://localhost via IE?

Tags: localhost, internet-explorer-7

But it's fine when I'm using firefox,

and in IE I can also open the page via 127.0.0.1

Anyone knows how to fix it for IE?

Comment: What error message do you get? What result did you expect?

Comment: Oh wow, THANK YOU for saying that you could connect using 127.0.0.1. I didn't think of that, and it's helped me get past this error at work. I LOVE YOU

Answer (score 20):

You should add `http://` before `localhost:port` for IE. Unlike other browsers, IE needs to know what protocol is being used.

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried typing only `localhost` and IE turned it to `http://localhost/` ..

Comment: Good habit is to include the protocol first; however if it is just `localhost` and no actual port number, you can usually just do what you stated and type `localhost` without issue.  If you need port numbers though, you should used the proper protocol format.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to try:

- try adding the port to localhost: localhost:80 or localhost:8080
- try checking proxy bypass settings for Internet Explorer (Tools -> Options), make sure it's set to proxy bypass for localhost
- Check `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and make sure the localhost entry is there

Comment: Under Windows 7, hosts no longer contains an entry for localhost (this is mentioned in the comments).

Comment: I tried all the above,but still not working.

Comment: localhost still works in Win7 for me, using the latest IE.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but I thought this may help someone.

Windows 7 Pro / IE 11

I had the exact same issue (http://localhost works in Chrome, and 127.0.0.1 worked in IE too). Tried various things like updating hosts file entry, disable ipv6 in network settings etc.. nothing worked.

Finally fixed by adding http://localhost to trusted site in IE Settings Internet Options>Security>Trusted sites. Make sure to un check the "Require Server verification (https).. " option when adding the trusted site address.

Answer (score 0):

If your local host uses default port(i.e 80) then it will resolve . If it uses different port then you will have to specify the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, 
it is because there some add-ons that always go to search engine when I browse to my localhost. So I just disable this add-ons in
Tools > Manage Add-ons > Click Search Provider > 
Set Default to Bing,

and my problem is gone.